# Unable to mock pinia store used in composable during vitest unit test

Tags: vuejs3, pinia, vitest, composable

I have a composable which is using stores. Now I am writing unit tests for the composable. And I want to test if an action of the used store was called. But I am not sure how to mock this store in the composable test.

I tried in three different ways to mock the store which are given below:

**1st way:**

```
const mockUpdateResponse = vi.fn()

vi.mock("@/stores/responseStore", async () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports
  const actual = await vi.importActual<typeof import("@/stores/responseStore")>("@/stores/responseStore")

  return {
    ...actual,
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
    userResponseStore: () => ({
      updateResponse: mockUpdateResponse,
    }),
  }
})
```

and then inside the test i perform the following expectation:

`expect(mockUpdateResponse).toBeCalledTimes(1)`

but this gives me the error: `AssertionError: expected "spy" to be called 1 times, but got 0 times`

**2nd Way:**

```
const mockUpdateResponse = vi.fn()

vi.mock("@/stores/responseStore", () => {
  const mockedResponseStore = vi.fn(() => ({
    updateResponse: mockUpdateResponse,
    clearResponse: mockClearResponse,
    updateResponsePackages: mockUpdatePackage,
  }))

  return {
    default: mockedResponseStore,
  }
})
```

then inside the test i perform the following expectation:
`expect(mockUpdateResponse).toBeCalledTimes(1)`

but this gives me the error: `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mockUpdateResponse' before initialization`

and this error is i guess expected because `vi.mock` call is hoisted to top of the file, so it was called before `const mockUpdateResponse = vi.fn()`.

**3rd Way:**

inside the test itself I wrote:

```
const pinia = createTestingPinia({
      createSpy: vi.fn,
      fakeApp: true,
})

setActivePinia(pinia)
const respStore = useResponseStore(pinia)

.....
some more lines of code
.....

expect(respStore.updateResponse).toBeCalledTimes(1)
```

This also gives me the first error: `AssertionError: expected "spy" to be called 1 times, but got 0 times`

I hope I provided enough explanation.